# Angular material auto complete inside text area

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Ok, here is the issue.  I am using Angular Material's inputs.  I want to use the auto-complete feature INSIDE a text area.  The reason is because `<md-auto-complete>` does not support line breaks and I need to be able to toggle the auto complete feature.  I want the auto complete feature to be part of the input, not the input itself.

Example:  Comment section of SO post. When you type in '@' there will be a suggestion of a user you want to direct the comment to.

In fact this is exactly what I am trying to achieve in my application.  I want users to be able to tag one another but need to auto complete feature as soon as they type in '@' + a single letter.

Here is the part of my code I am working with:

```
<label>Message</label>
                <textarea  ng-change="onMessageInput()" ng-model="newMessage" md-select-on-focus style="font-weight:bold;">
```

Here are my work-around idea:  inside the onMessageInput(), I can check for instances of '@' and use mdToast to show all possible people to tag.  I also want the feature to be able to press tab and select the first selection.  Not even Angular Materials mdAutoComplete has this.  You have to use the arrow and then tab, even if there is only one possible match.

Comment: It looks like this feature was requested, but closed without really being addressed: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1669